# How to add a simple Google map on my CakePHP webpage?

Tags: google-maps, cakephp

I have a problem to add a Google map on my cake PHP. Pleases give me some advice on how to add a simple Google map page on my webpage.

My code is here:

```
 class GooglemapsController extends AppController
{
    var $ext = ".php";
    public $helpers = array('GoogleMap');       
        public function index()
        {


        }
            public function map()
            {

            }
}`
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the iframe code in the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper. Simple way to add a map into your views and add markers and some more customization.

Answer (score 0):

```
[enter link description here][1]

Add below helper on app/view/helper/
```

`And add this code of default.ctp`

Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'); ?>
            Html->script('https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sen sor=true'); ?>

```
And Add below code on your view page:
  <?php
      $map_options = array(
        "id"         => "map_canvas",
        "width"      => "500px",
        "height"     => "500px",
        "localize"   => false,
        "zoom"       => 10,
        "address"    => "Manhattan, NY",
        "marker"     => true,
        "infoWindow" => true
      );
    ?>

    // print the default map
    <?= $this->GoogleMap->map($map_options); ?>

    // add the marker with latitude and longitude
    <?= $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas", 1, array("latitude" => 40.69847, "longitude" => -73.9514)); ?>

    // add the marker with address
    <?= $this->GoogleMap->addMarker("map_canvas", 2, "Queens, NY"); ?>
  [1]: https://github.com/marcferna/CakePHP-GoogleMapHelper/blob/master/GoogleMapHelper.php
```